# Closed questions being deleted and re-asked as new questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, closed-questions

This seems to be a phenomenon:

- Someone posts a question.
- Others ask them what they've tried / put the question on hold.
- The OP simply deletes the question, and re-asks it as a new question (and gets an answer).

Example 1: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753054/prove-that-there-exists-a-constant-c-such-that-zn-expz-1-z-o-expc) asked on 14 at 08:44, put on hold at 12:01, edited at 18:41, deleted on 15 (a day later) at 18:43, and re-asked as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755210/prove-that-there-exists-a-constant-c-such-that-zn-expz-1-z-o-expc-sq) at 18:43.

Example 2: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754425/solving-difference-equations-using-generation-functions) asked on 15 at 06:04, deleted at 07:03, and re-asked as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754462/using-generation-functions-solve-the-following-difference-equation) at 07:04.

In both cases, the questions are the same (verbatim) before and after.

How should one react to these? Is it even a problem?

(Note that despite 20k reputation it's not easy / possible to look at deleted questions: it's only by coincidence that I happened to have looked at both "before" and "after" versions, and had them in my history.)

Comment: I have a deja vu. Wasn't there a thread on this topic not long ago on the meta?

Comment: Re: *it's not easy / possible to look at deleted questions*. It is possible, but definitely not easy. One possibility how to find ids of deleted posts is mentioned in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/is-there-need-to-patrol-for-deleted-questions/8564#8564).

Comment: It is a self-correcting problem: self-deletion of questions, especially closed/downvoted ones, will quickly lead the user to [question ban](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flag the question, select "it needs moderator attention" and in the field provided explain that you believe the question is a duplicate of one of the user's deleted questions. We'll then use our superpowers to look into it.

Comment: Do you think this is a task for your x-ray vision? I have serious doubts that my ability to manipulate gravity will help at all. On the other hand, this might be just up the alley for robjohn's HULK SMASH!

Comment: @Arthur: Batman's main superpower is a gruff voice and the catchphrase "I'm Batman."; surely you can match that!